# How to run the script with the procedure that generates the plates of a state? and How to consult the plates created for the state of Querétaro?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have a project that requires solving the following questions:

- How to run the script with the procedure that generates the plates of a state?
  (probably requires tropicalizing the script)
- How to consult the plates created for the state of Querétaro?

the problem is that I don't know how to execute the instructions in postgreSQL, it allows me to create the tables and add data but to execute the instructions no longer. Some instructions are not from postgreSQL like "varchar2" and "numberic".

Note:

I have deleted the "comment on column / table" because it is not relevant. My postgresSSQL only works no graphical interfaces(pgAdmin 4)

```
-- EXECUTE GENERAPLACAS ('22,'TE')

create or replace procedure GENERAPLACAS(pestado in char,
                                         pservicio in char)  is
  Result number :=9;

-- Devuelve -1 El estado o el servicio no cuentan con un regisro de la serie a crear.
--          -2 No se pudo contar el número de placas generadas
--          -3 No se pudo recuperar la placa inicial ni final
--          -4 Cuando a serie ya ha sido creada.
--          -5 Estado = 09 o Servicio <> TE 
--          9n Se han creado 9n placas.

  vini      PSERIE.SERI_INI%TYPE;
  vfin      PSERIE.SERI_FIN%TYPE;
  vtotal    number := 0;
 -- Se declaran las letras y numeros para su posición correspondiente:
  li1       char(1);
  lf1       char(1);
  li2       char(1);
  lf2       char(1);
  li3       char(1);
  lf3       char(1);
  li4       char(1); 
  lf4       char(1);
  ni1       number;
  nf1       number;
  ni2       number;
  nf2       number;
  ni3       number;
  nf3       number;
  P1        number;
  P2        number;
  P3        number;
  P4        number;
  p7        number;
  total     number:=0;
  plk       char(8):=null;
  plkf      char(7);
begin
  IF (pestado IS NOT NULL) AND (pservicio IS NOT NULL) Then   -- El Servicio o estado NO es nulo
     BEGIN
       SELECT SERI_INI, SERI_FIN
         INTO vini, vfin
         FROM PSERIE
        WHERE SERI_ESTADO = pestado
          and SERI_SERVICIO = pservicio ;
       EXCEPTION                                             -- No pudo recuperarse la Placa inicial no final
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
               Result:=-1 ;
     END ;
     BEGIN
       SELECT COUNT(*)
         INTO vtotal
         FROM PPLACA
        WHERE PLAC_PLACA BETWEEN VINI AND VFIN ;
     EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN                                   -- No se pudo contar el número de placas
               Result:=-2 ;
     END ;
  ELSE                                                       -- El Servicio o estado es nulo
       Result:=-1 ;
  END IF;
  -- No cambio Result
  IF result = 9 THEN                -- Hay placa inicial y final y no marco error contar cuantas placas hay creadas
     begin  
        IF vtotal = 0 THEN          --  No hay placas creadas
           BEGIN
             IF PESTADO <> '09' AND PSERVICIO = 'TE' THEN   -- Se generan las placas, El DF ('09') se genera diferente
                BEGIN
                  li1:=substr(vini,1,1) ;
                  lf1:=substr(vfin,1,1) ;
                  li2:=substr(vini,2,1) ;
                  lf2:=substr(vfin,2,1) ;
                  li3:=substr(vini,3,1) ;
                  lf3:=substr(vfin,3,1) ;
                  ni1:=substr(vini,4,1) ;
                  nf1:=substr(vfin,4,1) ;
                  ni2:=substr(vini,5,1) ;
                  nf2:=substr(vfin,5,1) ;
                  ni3:=substr(vini,6,1) ;
                  nf3:=substr(vfin,6,1) ;
                  li4:=substr(vini,7,1) ;
                  lf4:=substr(vfin,7,1) ; 
-- I, Ñ, O, Q
-- 000
                  FOR P1 in ascii(li1)..ascii(lf1) LOOP
                     IF chr(p1) not in ('I', 'O', 'Q') THEN
                        FOR P2 in ascii(li2)..ascii(lf2) LOOP
                            IF chr(p2) not in ('I', 'O', 'Q') THEN
                               FOR p3 in ascii(li3)..ascii(lf3) LOOP
                                   IF chr(p3) not in ('I', 'O', 'Q') THEN
                                      FOR P4 in 1..999 LOOP
                                          FOR p7 in ascii(li4)..ascii(lf4) LOOP
                                             IF chr(p7) not in ('I', 'O', 'Q') THEN
                                                begin
                                                  total:=total+1;
                                                  plk:=null;
                                                  plk:=chr(p1) || chr(p2) || chr(p3) || to_char(p4,'009') || chr(p7) ;
                                                  plkf:=substr(plk,1,3) || substr(plk,5,4);
                                                  INSERT INTO PPLACA(PLAC_PLACA, PLAC_ESTADO)
                                                         VALUES (PLKF,pestado);
                                                  --plkf:=substr(plk,1,3) || substr(plk(5,4) ;
                                                  -- dbms_output.put_line(plkf);
                                                  --  || chr(p2) || chr(p3) || to_char(p4,'009') || chr(p7) ;
                                                end ;
                                              END IF;
                                          END LOOP ;  
                                          commit ;                                       
                                      END LOOP ;
                                   END IF;   
                               END LOOP;
                            END iF ;
                        END LOOP ;
                     END IF;
                  END LOOP;        
                  -- result:=ascii(li1) ;
                  result:=total;
                END ;                          
             ELSE
                result:=-5 ;
             END IF ;
           END ;
        ELSE
           result:=-4 ;            --  Ya ha sido creada la serie
        END IF;
     end ;
  END IF;
  if Result <> 9 then
     dbms_output.put_line('Error:  ' || to_char(Result,'0009'));
  end if;
end generaplacas;
```

Comment: Postgres or mysql?

Comment: I have to do it in postgres, I don't know in what language he got this code my teacher

Comment: `dbms_output.put_line` is an Oracle package/function. You can see the [wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Oracle_to_Postgres_Conversion) for some conversion guidance